# Generate random values to mimic skewness

Tags: python, scikit-learn, skewness, numpy, skew-normal-distribution

I have a actual set of data where the variables are heavily skewed, both positively and negatively.

I need to generate random sample data for the values going forward. The data needs to be similarly skewed for the variables, so that the covariance and correlation remain reasonably similar.

I had planned to use numpy.random.multivariate_normal(), as I can easily determine the mean, and covariance values for the data set. However, as the data is skewed, it is not normal.

Using numpy, or sklearn, is there a random number package that can produce similarly skewed data?

The skewnesses of the variables, if anybody is interested are as follows:

```
 rain    2.373325
 temp   -0.286573
 rhum   -0.289834
 sun     1.103147
 vis    -0.303844
```

Comment: On those numbers, only one of those looks  even close to heavily skew (rain), but I wouldn't call it that heavy. One looks moderately skew (sun). The others are mildly skew. There are many possible multivariate models to choose from; if I had to simulate something like this I'd probably look to copulas. How much data do you have, and why do you need to simulate?

Comment: Will look at cupolas, and see if they work. For each column of data, I have 260k points to simulate, each within a particular range of correlation (+noise), against the other datapoints.

Comment: *Why* do you need to simulate?

Comment: Need the data to help determine the possible weather patterns going forward.